# Why does this SwiftCharts line chart jump when starting to pan to the right

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

I'm creating a chart using SwiftCharts based on the Trendline example provided with the library. In my application, I'm charting weight lifting events showing the single highest lift weight on each distinct day. In my example, I'm charting 4  Bench Press events.

The chart renders when the view controller is first displayed, but when I pan to the right it stutters, spreads out, and the points move. This is what that looks like:

[image]

Note that when the chart is first rendered, the lowest plotted value (208.0) appears to be between Mar 12 and Mar 13, yet after it does that stutter thing, the point moves to the right of Mar 13.

The `chartPoints` being plotted are:

```
▿ 4 elements
  ▿ 0 : Mar 12, 239.17
  ▿ 1 : Mar 13, 208
  ▿ 2 : Mar 15, 267.17
  ▿ 3 : Mar 18, 240
```

Here's the view controller:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftCharts

class ChartViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var chart: Chart? // arc
    fileprivate let dataManager = CoreDataHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let labelSettings = ChartLabelSettings(font: ChartDefaults.labelFont)

        let liftEventTypeUuid = "98608870-E3CE-476A-B1E4-018D2AE4BDBF"

        let liftEvents = dataManager.fetchLiftsEventsOfType(liftEventTypeUuid)

        let dailyLiftEvents = liftEvents.reduce(into: [Date:[LiftEvent]](), { dailyLiftEvents, currentLiftEvent in
            dailyLiftEvents[Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentLiftEvent.date), default: [LiftEvent]()].append(currentLiftEvent)
        })
        let dailyMaxLiftEvents = dailyLiftEvents.map({$0.value.max(by: {$0.oneRepMax < $1.oneRepMax})})
        var sortedLiftEvents = dailyMaxLiftEvents.sorted(by: { $0?.date.compare(($1?.date)!) == .orderedAscending })


        var readFormatter = DateFormatter()
        readFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

        var displayFormatter = DateFormatter()
        displayFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"

        let date = {(str: String) -> Date in
            return readFormatter.date(from: str)!
        }

        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let dateWithComponents = {(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) -> Date in
            var components = DateComponents()
            components.day = day
            components.month = month
            components.year = year
            return calendar.date(from: components)!
        }

        func filler(_ date: Date) -> ChartAxisValueDate {
            let filler = ChartAxisValueDate(date: date, formatter: displayFormatter)
            filler.hidden = true
            return filler
        }

        let chartPoints = sortedLiftEvents.map { ChartPoint(x: ChartAxisValueDate(date: ($0?.date)!, formatter: displayFormatter), y: ChartAxisValueDouble(($0?.calculateOneRepMax().value)!)) }

        let highestWeight = sortedLiftEvents.last??.oneRepMax.value
        let lowestWeight = sortedLiftEvents.first??.oneRepMax.value

        let yValues = stride(from: roundToTen(x: lowestWeight! - 40), through: roundToTen(x: highestWeight! + 40), by: 20).map {ChartAxisValueDouble(Double($0), labelSettings: labelSettings)}

        let xGeneratorDate = ChartAxisValuesGeneratorDate(unit: .day, preferredDividers: 2, minSpace: 1, maxTextSize: 12)
        let xLabelGeneratorDate = ChartAxisLabelsGeneratorDate(labelSettings: labelSettings, formatter: displayFormatter)
        let firstDate = sortedLiftEvents.first??.date
        let lastDate = sortedLiftEvents.last??.date

        let xModel = ChartAxisModel(firstModelValue: (firstDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!, lastModelValue: (lastDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!, axisTitleLabels: [ChartAxisLabel(text: "Date", settings: labelSettings)], axisValuesGenerator: xGeneratorDate, labelsGenerator: xLabelGeneratorDate)

        let yModel = ChartAxisModel(axisValues: yValues, axisTitleLabel: ChartAxisLabel(text: "1-RM", settings: labelSettings.defaultVertical()))
        let chartFrame = ChartDefaults.chartFrame(view.bounds)

        var chartSettings = ChartDefaults.chartSettingsWithPanZoom // was ChartDefaults.chartSettings
        chartSettings.trailing = 80

        // Set a fixed (horizontal) scrollable area 2x than the original width, with zooming disabled.
        chartSettings.zoomPan.maxZoomX = 2
        chartSettings.zoomPan.minZoomX = 2
        chartSettings.zoomPan.minZoomY = 1
        chartSettings.zoomPan.maxZoomY = 1

ChartAxisValuesStaticGenerator.generateYAxisValuesWithChartPoints(chartPoints, minSegmentCount: 10, maxSegmentCount: 20, multiple: 2, axisValueGenerator: {ChartAxisValueDouble($0, labelSettings: labelSettings)}, addPaddingSegmentIfEdge: false)

        let lineModel = ChartLineModel(chartPoints: chartPoints, lineColor: UIColor.red, lineCap: .round ,animDuration: 1, animDelay: 0)

        let trendLineModel = ChartLineModel(chartPoints: TrendlineGenerator.trendline(chartPoints), lineColor: UIColor.blue, animDuration: 0.5, animDelay: 1)

        let coordsSpace = ChartCoordsSpaceLeftBottomSingleAxis(chartSettings: chartSettings, chartFrame: chartFrame, xModel: xModel, yModel: yModel)
        let (xAxisLayer, yAxisLayer, innerFrame) = (coordsSpace.xAxisLayer, coordsSpace.yAxisLayer, coordsSpace.chartInnerFrame)

        let chartPointsLineLayer = ChartPointsLineLayer(xAxis: xAxisLayer.axis, yAxis: yAxisLayer.axis, lineModels: [lineModel])

        let trendLineLayer = ChartPointsLineLayer(xAxis: xAxisLayer.axis, yAxis: yAxisLayer.axis, lineModels: [trendLineModel])

        let settings = ChartGuideLinesDottedLayerSettings(linesColor: UIColor.black, linesWidth: ChartDefaults.guidelinesWidth)
        let guidelinesLayer = ChartGuideLinesDottedLayer(xAxisLayer: xAxisLayer, yAxisLayer: yAxisLayer, settings: settings)

        let chart = Chart(
            frame: chartFrame,
            innerFrame: innerFrame,
            settings: chartSettings,
            layers: [
                xAxisLayer,
                yAxisLayer,
                guidelinesLayer,
                chartPointsLineLayer,
                trendLineLayer
            ]
        )

        view.addSubview(chart.view)
        self.chart = chart
    }

    private struct liftWeightItem {
        let number: Int
        let text: String

        init(number: Int, text: String) {
            self.number = number
            self.text = text
        }
    }

    private struct liftDateItem {
        let name: String
        let quantity: liftWeightItem

        init(name: String, quantity: liftWeightItem) {
            self.name = name
            self.quantity = quantity
        }
    }

    func createChartPoint(dateStr: String, percent: Double, readFormatter: DateFormatter, displayFormatter: DateFormatter) -> ChartPoint {
        return ChartPoint(x: createDateAxisValue(dateStr, readFormatter: readFormatter, displayFormatter: displayFormatter), y: ChartAxisValueDouble(percent))
    }

    func createDateAxisValue(_ dateStr: String, readFormatter: DateFormatter, displayFormatter: DateFormatter) -> ChartAxisValue {
        let date = readFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
        let labelSettings = ChartLabelSettings(font: ChartDefaults.labelFont, rotation: 45, rotationKeep: .top)
        return ChartAxisValueDate(date: date, formatter: displayFormatter, labelSettings: labelSettings)
    }

    func roundToTen(x : Double) -> Int {
        return 10 * Int(round(x / 10.0))
    }

    class ChartAxisValuePercent: ChartAxisValueDouble {
        override var description: String {
            return "\(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: scalar))!)%"
        }
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the rendering of the x-axis so I've tried adjusting the `preferredDividers` and `minSpace` values:

```
let xGeneratorDate = ChartAxisValuesGeneratorDate(unit: .day, preferredDividers: 2, minSpace: 1, maxTextSize: 12)
```

but that not only doesn't fix the problem, it results in a new one I'll post about separately.

I've read through the documentation several times but I still haven't been able to figure it out. This is a beautifully written library so I'd really like to be able to use it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a better place to ask @Ixx (the author) question like this?

Comment: I will give it a look this week!

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal runnable example?

Comment: @Ixx - I added you as a contributor the my Github repo. Branch is 'feature/chart-Ixx'. Just enter a Weight, number of Reps, and tap Calculate, then Save. Do this to create 3 or 4 liftEvents so there's something to display on the chart. Access the chart from the Lift Log screen using the icon at the top.

Comment: @Ixx, you should have received an invitation to the repo. Let me know if you didn't or if you need anything else.

Comment: Should be fixed! Some layers require an additional call after the chart has been initialized, when the chart has an initial zoom level. This is admittedly a bit weird but I haven't had the time to polish this api. There's an example containing this code - next time you come across something try looking for similar examples and see if it's solved there!

Comment: @Ixx - it works perfectly! Thank you so much! I did read about delayInit in your documentation but I didn't make the connection that this was the cause. If you want to add an answer I'll accept it. If you don't, I'll add the answer for the benefit of others who may experience the same issue.

Comment: You can answer it, no problem :) I'll try to make this clearer in the wiki.